# Visual basic console application controlling form application

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2012, binding, console

I am trying to make a VB 2012 project where a console application combines with a form application. My main goal is to be able to type commands on a console and change properties or displays on the forms.

The idea came when want to teach my students how to use what they know together with what they see to be able manipulate programs.

I wanted to make a program with a plot that allows student to be in a mind frame that gives them a purpose to the task.

I wanted to make the project where there are 3 form windows,

1: door access screen saying " Door 342" with an image of a door and a colour dot. Then when the right command is entered in the console then the colour dot would change from Red (closed/locked) to Green (Open/Unlocked)

2: Security alarm system, running basically the same but with a fail safe where if something is entered wrong then an error message pops up or a timer starts timing down before the alarm triggers.

3: Pressure pipe system, where they see tubes and then if the alarm triggers then the pressure if sealing doors so a colour strip follows the pipe to each door which would have to be monitored and shutdown if triggered.

I can write form applications and console applications but i can seem to be able to get a joining one.

The best i have come up with is by making a button on a form that writes into a console without feedback from the console.

Please help as it is something that I would like to make so that i can teach and have fun at the same time for the higher level students.

Many thanks for your help in the matter.

Comment: You could make the applications communicate via [TCP or UDP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c19ex43h(v=vs.110).aspx). If you use TCP, the TcpListener could be set to only listen to localhost (which is IP address `127.0.0.1`). Otherwise there's also [Window messaging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19740/Send-strings-to-another-application-by-using-Windo).

Comment: While more advanced than TCP/UDP, you could also use `WSDualHttpBinding` in WCF. [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Educator's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators))